# Get Position on Non-Absolute Element Relative to Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

Right now I have a Jade template that is rendering very well and set up like this:

```
div.rulers
    div.ruler-con.js.this-site
        div.ui.red.progress
            div.label jQuery
            div.bar.jquery
    div.ruler-con.js.template.pretty-good
        div.ui.red.progress
            div.label Underscore JS
            div.bar.underscore.pretty-good
    div.ruler-con.js.pretty-good
        div.ui.red.progress
            div.label Angular JS
            div.bar.angular.pretty-good
    div.ruler-con.js.this-site.server.scripting
        div.ui.red.progress
            div.label Node JS
            div.bar.node
```

The parent div **div.rulers** has a CSS rule of position relative. What I am trying to do is find out each **div.ruler-con** position top relative to **div.rulers**, from where it is sitting in the layout. Basically, I want to know, if each **div.ruler-con** was position absolute what would it's position top be relative to **div.rulers**. I have tried:

```
var top = $(skill).position();

console.log(top);
```

and:

```
var top = $(skill).offset();

console.log(top);
```

Both are returning `top:0` and `left:0`. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could get this value?

For reference, the variable '*skill*' is each **div.ruler-con** as a variable in a loop. I am looping through all of these **div.ruler.con**

Thanks,

**Edit:**

Here is my javascript now:

```
var _skills = {
    each: function(skill_function, other) {
        $('div.ruler-con').each(function(i, value) {
            _skill_function(value, other)
        });
    },
    set: function(skill) {
        var top = $(skill).position();

        console.log(top);
    },
    filter: function(skill, class) {
        if ($(skill).hasClass(class)) {
            $(skill).fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(skill).fadeOut();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `top: 0` and `left: 0` is correct, elements that are not positioned (have default `position: static`) are part of the DOM flow, whereas positioned elements are outside it - you're mixing two different things.

Comment: @Luca, that makes sense. I kind of already drew that conclusion. Now I am looking for a work around or alternative.

Comment: In JavaScript, you'd use `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft`.

Comment: I don't know why ,position() doesn't work for you, works for me. Could you show your JS?

Comment: @CookieMan, that is all the javascript I am currently using. These elements are hard coded into the HTML so there shouldn't be any loading issues.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin but did you tried looping through elements and then get position of each element? take a look at example - http://jsfiddle.net/9L89m4zo/

Comment: @CookieMan added code above that applies to the issue

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/position/) regardless position() method:

> Description: Get the current coordinates **of the first element** in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

So it is correct, that value you gettings is `{top: 0, left: 0}`, because the first `div.ruler.con` in your set of elements is most likely not positioned absolutely.

To get position of each individual element, you have to loop first through these elements, and then use position() method on the element:

```
var _skills = {
    each: function(skill_function, other) {
        $('div.ruler-con').each(function(i, value) {
            _skill_function(value, other);
        });
    },
    set: function(skill) {
        $(skill).each(function() {
            console.log( $(this).position() );
        });
    },
    filter: function(skill, className) {
        if ($(skill).hasClass(className)) {
            $(skill).fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(skill).fadeOut();
        }
    }
};
```